# PowerShell 7 Remoting from Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: powershell-7.0, powershell-7.2

We were using Azure DevOps Pipelines and PowerShell Remoting to execute PS1 scripts:

```
trigger: none

jobs:
  - job: PSRemoting
    timeoutInMinutes: 5760
    pool:
      name: 'DevOps-Agent2-VM'
    steps:
    - checkout: none

    - task: PowerShellOnTargetMachines@3
      displayName: 'PSRemoting'
      inputs:
        Machines: '$(VM-PublicIP)'
        UserName: '$(VM-UserName)'
        UserPassword: '$(VM-Password)'
        InlineScript: |
          . C:\Scripts\Test-Parallel.ps1
```

We have added `-parallel` feature that requires PowerShell 7 and our scripts are failing now:

```
2022-11-02T13:37:18.3246154Z ForEach-Object : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At line:1 char:1
+ & 'C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe' -NoLogo ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (ForEach-Object ...med parameters.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 

At C:\Scripts\Test-Parallel.ps1:3 char:10

+ $items | ForEach-Object -Parallel {

+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (:) [ForEach-Object], ParentContainsErrorRecordExcep 

   tion

    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ForEachObjectCo 

   mmand

 

##[error]Non-Zero exit code: '1' for ComputerName: 'VM1'
##[error]Atleast one remote job failed. Consult logs for more details. ErrorCodes(s): 'RemoteDeployer_NonZeroExitCode'
##[section]Finishing: PSRemoting
```

Here is `Test-Parallel.ps1`:

```
$items = 1..100
 
$items | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
  Write-Host "$(Get-Date) | Sleeping for 1 second..."
  Start-Sleep 1
} -ThrottleLimit 10
```

How can we force PowerShell to run version 7 with our Azure DevOps Pipeline task?

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your `Test-Parallel.ps1` script:

```
workflow Test-PipelineDeploy {
  $items = 1..100

  foreach -parallel ($item in $items) {
    Write-Host "$(Get-Date) | Sleeping for 1 second..."
    Start-Sleep 1
  } -ThrottleLimit 10 
}
```

Then call `Test-PipelineDeploy`

Comment: Also, I think -parallel requires this to be wrapped in a workflow.

Comment: We don't need to rewrite PowerShell 7 code to work with PowerShell 5, we need to run PowerShell remoting successfully with PowerShell 7 scripts.

Comment: Ah, I see, the remote PC PSRemoting is defaulting to v5.  This doc should help solve this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/enable-psremoting?view=powershell-7.2

Whatever version of PS you run the ```enable-psremoting``` command in is the version that will run remoting.  So you will have to launch PS v7 and run ```enable-psremoting```.  You should be able to create the v7 remoting endpoint from a v5 instance.

Comment: I tried `Enable-PSRemoting` with this script https://pastebin.com/ikfLS629 from PowerShell 7 pwsh.exe and now I'm getting `access is denied` when trying to `Enter-PSSession`  https://pastebin.com/w9c8hLVQ. I'm able to connect when doing `Enable-PSRemoting` from PowerShell 5.

Comment: @WinBoss Any update about your solution or workaround? Did you manage to find a solution using PowerShellOnTargetMachines@3 and PowerShell 7?